# Printing out hash (dictionary) using hash class python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, hash

I have an assignment to create a hash class in python, to implement on a text file containing restriction enzymes, with sequences in the first column and the RE name in the second. The goal is to create a random 6bp sequence, and see if it exists in the text file by printing out the corresponding enzyme name. I can do this with just lists, and turning it into a dictionary, and using get() to retrieve the corresponding enzyme name, however I must create a class.

Here is the hash class, and random sequence generator (there may be indentation errors when pasting):

```
class KeyValue:
    def __init__(self,key,value):
        self.key=key
        self.value=value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.key)+":"+str(self.value)
class HashTable:

    def __init__(self, SIZE):
        i=0
        self.list=[]
        for i in range(SIZE):
            self.list.append([])
            i=i+1
        self.SIZE = len(self.list)

    def getValue(self,key):
        h = self.hash(key)
        bucket = self.list[h]
        for kv in bucket:
            if kv.key==key:
                return kv.value
    def setValue(self,key,value):
        h = self.hash(key)
        # should search first so we don't put key in twice, but for now ignore
        self.list[h].append(KeyValue(key,value))

    def hash(self, key):
        i=0
        total=0
        while i<len(key):
            total = total+ord(key[i])
            i=i+1
        return total % self.SIZE

def random_DNA(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice('ATCG') for _ in xrange(length))
```

Here is the code, used to import the module:

```
from HashTable import *

fh = open("restriction_enzymes.txt", "r")

num_lines = int(sum(1 for line in fh))

print num_lines

hashtable = HashTable(int(num_lines))

for line in fh:
    (key, value) = line.strip().split('t')
    hashtable.setValue(key, value)

print hashtable

DNA = random_DNA(6)
print DNA
print hastable.getValue(DNA)
print hashtable.getValue('AACGTT')
```

First, I want to be able to print out the hash table. I want to be able to visualize the dictionary. When attempting to do that with the line " print hashtable" after it is created, I get the output: "HashTable.HashTable instance at 0x7ff53555db90", which I guess is the location in memory? Do I have to implement a **str** or **repr** function in the HashTable class? Can someone assist with this?

Regarding the main output of the program, if I put the variable DNA, the random seq, in for "print hashtable.getValue(DNA)", I get the output of "None". Ok, so that random seq isn't in there. So, I tried copying and pasting the first seq from the text file 'AACGTT' which corresponds to the RE AclI. However, I still get the output "None". Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

All the seq identifiers in the text file are either 4, 6, or 8 bp long. Since the random sequence is 6, does using the hash function know to pull it if it's 4 or 8 and the 6 bp seq matches somewhere in the 4 or 8? Or should I implement a function to try and pull it based on nucleotide matches?

All help is appreciated. Best.